# Visual Studio, Beautify issue(Optional chaining operator)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, js-beautify

[image: Option changing operator]

Every time when I format the script with the beautify the optional chaining operator splits from (`?.`) to (`? .`). Is there any config or something that I can do to avoid this issue?

Comment: Yes. The ECMAScript version needs to be at least 2020.

Comment: works fine in their online version, you may have either an old one, or language settings set to something before optional chaining was introduced. It's still a bad sign, when it does an illegal transformation, instead of giving an error.